# Inference on asymptotically biased estimators

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, asymptotics

For simple estimators (e.g. sample mean, OLS), we typically establish asymptotic normality by appealing to some type of Central Limit Theorem
$$ \sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}]) \to^d \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma) $$
If the estimator is asymptotically unbiased s.t. $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}] = \beta$ is the parameter we care about, it is then straightforward to construct confidence intervals.

However suppose that $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}] = \beta + \nu$, where $\nu$ is some non-zero bias term that does not tend to zero as $n \to \infty$. How would we perform inference in such a case?

---

An example is the kernel regression estimator, where it can be shown that the optimal choice of bandwidth (in the squared error sense) has an asymptotic bias. The solution in the literature seems to be to "undersmooth" the estimator, by choosing a bandwidth smaller than the optimal one, thereby removing the bias but at the expense of increasing variance (loss of efficiency). Are there other ways to handle inference on biased estimators?

Comment: The bias in a kernel estimator *does* go to zero as $n\to\infty$, it just doesn't go to zero faster than $n^{-1/2}$.  I think you need to clarify whether you are interested in bias that doesn't go to zero, or in bias that does go to zero but isn't asymptotically negligible (as in a kernel estimator)